# Trouble with installing GiNaC on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c++

I am trying to install GiNaC on Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed `ginac-tools` as well as `libginac-dev` but my code won't run.

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ginac/ginac.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace GiNaC;

    int main()
    {
         symbol x("x"), y("y");
         ex poly;

         for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
             poly += factorial(i+16)*pow(x,i)*pow(y,2-i);

         cout << poly << endl;
         return 0;
    }
```

Below is a small section of what the error message is. It goes on for quite some time.

```
/tmp/ccniH1BR.o: In function main':<br/>/home/greenbur/Delete_Me.cpp:8: undefined reference toGiNaC::symbol::symbol(std::cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
/home/greenbur/Delete_Me.cpp:8: undefined reference to `GiNaC::symbol:
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of linking GiNaC library.

Add libraries when compiling the source code.

**g++ -o ProjectName YourSourceCode.cpp -lcln -lginac**

Comment: This compiles in Emacs and my terminal but won't run in Atom while using gpp-compiler extension, any idea why? Also, I tried giving you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation to do so, haha.